# Get remoteField name in Grails controller action

Tags: grails, view, controller, action, gsp

I have a Grails gsp view with a remoteField. The remoteField calls a controller action.
In the controller action I would like to know the name of the remoteField that invoked the controller action.

Thank you,
Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an attribute like name or id to your remoteField tag and in your controller you will access it through the params.

```
    <g:remoteField id="myId" controller="book" action="changeTitle" update="titleDiv"  
    name="title"    value="${book?.name}" />
```

in controller

```
  def changeTitle() {
     println params.id
  }
```